# Car package not found by R (failed to load)

Tags: r, r-car

I am am trying to load a simple dataset using:

```
library(car)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in library("car") : there is no package called 'car'
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: install.packages("car")

Answer (score 9):

If you don't currently use an IDE (or even if you do), the following will install the package:

```
install.packages("car")
```

Before then running

```
library("car")
```

You should heed @Iris's advice and use a RStudio if you don't already to manage just this sort of task.

Comment: I still cannot install car library after running `install.packages("car")`, there is always a error: `Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘pbkrtest’ 0.4-2 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.4 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘car’ was built under R version 3.2.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’`

Comment: @JW.ZG You should open this as another question. If/when you do, add the results of `sessionInfo()` and this will help others diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to install the package before you tried to load it.

Do you use a IDE (integrated development environment)? I can strongly recommmand the use of Rstudio as IDE. 
When you installed Rstudio, you can choose in the toolbar: "Tools" > "Install packages..."
Type in "car" and click "install".
As soon as the package is installed, you can load the package with `library(car)`

Answer (score 1):

I know this post was from several months ago, but I came across it after having the same issue. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDgQFjAEahUKEwi6s-W4yvrIAhUGOSYKHVcbB-o&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepage.stat.uiowa.edu%2F~rdecook%2Fstat3200%2Flabs%2FInstalling%2520the%2520CAR%2520package.doc&usg=AFQjCNFBvYahFOtyoFK3WNNjzmMKUM0fLQ) (it's a .doc download).

I typically use R Studio, but was having no luck with this:

```
install.packages("car")
```

I opened the R application (not Studio) and followed the instructions on the .doc. I now have the package. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For security purposes, I use R in a standard account on a Mac and download packages via a separate admin account. Yesterday I updated Microsoft R Open from 3.2.2 to 3.2.3 and I got this message when I tried to load Rcmdr:

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck         = vI[[j]]) : 
>             namespace ‘nlme’ 3.1-122 is being loaded, but >= 3.1.123 is required
>           Error: package ‘car’ could not be loaded

I had to log in to my admin account and check for updates. There was one for nlme, that I installed and that allowed car to load.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. After downloading the most stable version of R (3.4.4), first, I install.packages("car",dependencies=TRUE) then install all the packages that when loading car I was asked for like haven, foreign, etc. So I installed them separately. Also, I noticed that when I install the packages they go to win-library folder instead of the actual working folder (the packages go to R\win-library\3.4 instead of R\R-3.4.4. So I copied them to the right folder.

Answer (score 1):

I used Tools/Install packages... from R Studio and chose not to compile from source and do this for several packages it complains missing. And it works!