# Persistent problems installing the car package in R

Tags: r, package, installation

I'm having problems installing the package `car` in R.

There are previous posts on the topic, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27858474/4089351) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31928401/4089351).

I have followed the suggestions I've come across so far without success. I am using R Version 3.2.2. and RStudio.

This is the message I get:

```
install.packages("car")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/car_2.1-3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1447213 bytes (1.4 MB)
downloaded 1.4 MB

package ‘car’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpc3xr5i\downloaded_packages
```

If I check I get,

```
?car
No documentation for ‘car’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??car’
```

I tried installing it from R with `Install packages from local zip drives`, and looking for the zip in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpc3xr5i\downloaded_packages`, but this is the result:

```
library(car)
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘SparseM’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘car’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’
```

---

I did try installing `SparseM` even before posting the OP without success:

```
> install.packages("SparseM")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/SparseM_1.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 795531 bytes (776 KB)
downloaded 776 KB

package ‘SparseM’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpc3xr5i\downloaded_packages
> ?SparseM
No documentation for ‘SparseM’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??SparseM’
```

---

Follow up:

After a comment regarding R version 3.2.3 I thought it would be an easy fix to just download this version, install, and erase 3.2.2. The problem then is that RStudio did not seem to work. I un-installed and re-installed R-studio, and now I get this when opening R studio:

[image]

Comment: are you able to upgrade your r version, as some of the import packages depend on later r versions

Comment: Your error message is possibly incomplete. Was there a message before the `car` install results that mentioned something about `SparseM`? When I install `car`, I get an explicit dependency on `SparseM`, so if it isn't available for your arch/Rversion, it will raise an error. (Perhaps try `install.packages("SparseM")` and edit your question with the results.)

Comment: @r2evans; i think issues will persist as it imports [pkbrtest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/index.html) which needs R >3.2.3

Comment: `pkbrtest` is not included anywhere in the `DESCRIPTION`, but now I see that it did install. You may be right, I was just feeding off the `'SparseM' not found` (which is still supported for R-3.2.2). Perhaps `SparseM` was a momentary failed install, where another attempt will work just fine (that's happened to me). Won't know until OP comes back with edits/comments.

Comment: @r2evans, pkbrtest is in the imports  section of the DESCRIPTION file. But your right installing `SparseM` would normally be the first suggestion (although they do say they tries the suggestion in the links ie `install.packages(... dependencies=TRUE)` ) . But [pkbrtest is a known issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207624/package-pbkrtest-is-not-available-for-r-version-3-2-2)  : knew i'd seen it somewhere ;)

Comment: I can't read, apparently. Thanks. (Actually, it was a dyslexic `grep`, easy to do with a name like that.)

Comment: ha <copy and paste> is my friend with that one

Comment: The message "No documentation" is normal, and does nothing to indicate if a package is installed (try `?somethingnotinstalled`). One method is `packageVersion("SparseM")`, but a better follow-on: now that `SparseM` is installed, have you retried `library(car)`? If @user20650 is correct, you'll likely get an error about `pkbrtest`.

Comment: Try an reinstall rstudio - it also depends on the rversion

Comment: @user20650 I did a couple of times without success...

Comment: okay,  so you are on windows. So just to check can you access R using the default windows rgui?

Comment: Yes, I can access R.

Comment: v 3.3.1 i assume. if so,  i can only suggest going into control panel >uninstall programs > rstudio, and then trying to install rstudio again.

Comment: install the [most up to date r version from cran] (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/). Then reinstall rstudio.

Comment: Which version is the latest?

Comment: see link ^^   ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing what version of the **car** package you're using, it's hard to know exactly what the source of the problem is. It seems likely, however, that you haven't installed the proper version of the **pbkrtest**, on which the **Rcmdr** package depends.

Is there a compelling reason not to upgrade everything to their current versions, including R, all packages, and RStudio?

Best,
 John

Comment: I tried doing all this. Right now the problems that all this have caused on my laptop make the package car a remote thought... No R... No RStudio...

Comment: @Toni; you said in the comments above you had R - accessed by the rgui. It seemed you upgraded from 3.2.2 to 3.2.3, however, it is definitely best to upgrade to the current stable r version (link above). Can you do that and then respond that you can access r v3.3.1 via the rgui (ignoring your issue with car and rstudio just now)

Comment: @user20650 Thank you very much for all your help. I would need a full page to describe what I have done to go back to baseline. I'll comb through all your comments later or tomorrow. Thanks, again!